# Many domains with SSL in Nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl

I have many domains like `hello1.com`, `hello2.com` ... `hello101.com`
All of them having SSL Certificates by Let's encrypt.
All of this domains need to be proxied to this URI `http://127.0.0.1:8000`  (`django` is there and it will handle everything)

So, this is `Nginx` config for one domain:

```
server {
    listen  80 default_server;
    return 404;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name         hello.com;

    location ~ ^/(static|media)/ {
        root            /hosting/hello/files;
        expires         30d;
    }
    location / {
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
         proxy_pass     http://127.0.0.1:8000;
         proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding  "";
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/hello.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/hello.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

But if I want to config all my servers, there will be a lot of repeating lines of code and it will be very difficult to maintain.

Only 3 lines of configuration are different for each domain:

```
server_name        <domain>.com;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain>.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain>.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
```

How can I move all other lines to one place? I don't want to repeat this configuration 100 times.

---

UPD: I can wildcard `server_name` or list all domains like this:

```
server_name   hello1.com hello2.com hello3.com etc.
```

Then I'll need to put current domain name (is it in `$host` variable?) into this 2 strings:

```
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain>/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain>/privkey.pem;
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Perhaps you can use wildcards in the `server_name`, otherwise I would look into scripting it.

Comment: @Tommiie, how can I wildcard it?

Comment: Read the documentation: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Comment: I can wildcard `server_name`, but I also need to put domain name here: `ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain>.com/fullchain.pem;` - is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use different TLS certificates for each name, then you also need to have separate `server` blocks.

If you have all of the names on the same TLS certificate, then those server names can also share the same `server` block. To create such a certificate, you would provide multiple `-d` options to `certbot` at the same time, e.g. `certbot ... -d domain1 -d domain2 -d domain3`.

In either case, you can use `include` yourself to create configuration snippets which you can share among multiple `server` blocks.